# ROS2 Docker: Node/topics not showing up in list

Tags: ros2, docker

I've set up ROS 2 Humble in Docker with NoVNC following [these](https://divyanshu-raj.medium.com/ros-2-with-docker-part-1-9060f3095811) instructions with the intention of doing the turtle sim tutorials. However, I can't see any nodes or topics using the list command and my subscriber isn't receiving any messages. I have made sure to set ROS_DOMAIN_ID to 0 in all terminal windows and also tried starting/stopping the dameon (rqt graph also shows no nodes or topics).

Would really appreciate some help as I'm just trying to get started with ROS and this has been quite frustrating. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! It is better to paste the text from the terminal rather than screenshots. Images are not text-searchable. Thank you for your kind cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

I got into the same issue. Turns out in my `.bashrc` I've set the `ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY` variable as 1. Switched it back to 0 (By default it is zero) and it started working for me.